# encode string in php decode in javascript & maintain structure

Tags: javascript, php, encode

In PHP I have data scraped a sit and produced the following string ( shortened there are over 130 rows).

```
[{
  "0name":"LNE-54V150WAAA DISTRI # 1145-1187-ND",
  "1name":"Delta Electronics Inc",
  "2name":"LED DRIVER CC/CV AC/DC 54V 2.8A",
  "3name":"56 In Stock",
  "4name":"100 £35.8441 50 £39.1026 25 £41.7096 10 £42.3620 5 £44.3160 1 £45.6200 See More",
  "5name":"Buy Now"
}, {
  "0name":"LNE-54V150WDAA DISTRI # 1145-1188-ND",
  "1name":"Delta Electronics Inc",
  "2name":"LED DRIVER CC/CV AC/DC 54V 2.8A",
  "3name":"53 In Stock",
  "4name":"100 £35.8441 50 £39.1026 25 £41.7096 10 £42.3620 5 £44.3160 1 £45.6200 See More",
  "5name":"Buy Now"
}]
```

I use `echo '['.$arrayBare.']';`

When I paste this into http://json.parser.online.fr it show as a json array correctly.

Now I need to use this in javascript. I have tried various methods in PHP and javascript but cannot maintain the structure.

Comment: I showed you how to decode in both PHP and JavaScript. The JavaScript is plain JavaScript. Do you use jQuery, because if so I can show you a little example of that too.

Answer (score 0):

## Simple examples of json decoding in PHP and JavaScript

Try PHP's json_decode function. This is tested in PHP and it works:

```
$str = '[{"0name":"LNE-54V150WAAA DISTRI # 1145-1187-ND","1name":"Delta Electronics Inc","2name":"LED DRIVER CC/CV AC/DC 54V 2.8A","3name":"56 In Stock","4name":"100 £35.8441 50 £39.1026 25 £41.7096 10 £42.3620 5 £44.3160 1 £45.6200 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V150WDAA DISTRI # 1145-1188-ND","1name":"Delta Electronics Inc","2name":"LED DRIVER CC/CV AC/DC 54V 2.8A","3name":"53 In Stock","4name":"100 £35.8441 50 £39.1026 25 £41.7096 10 £42.3620 5 £44.3160 1 £45.6200 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V185WDAA DISTRI # 1145-1190-ND","1name":"Delta Electronics Inc","2name":"LED DRIVER CC/CV AC/DC 54V 3.45A","3name":"49 In Stock","4name":"100 £37.7587 50 £41.1914 25 £43.9376 10 £44.6240 5 £46.6840 1 £48.0600 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"PME264NE5470MR30 DISTRI # 399-7467-ND","1name":"KEMET Corporation","2name":"CAP FILM 0.047UF 20% 660VAC RAD","3name":"26 In Stock","4name":"5000 £0.9579 2500 £0.9948 1000 £1.0316 500 £1.1790 100 £1.5474 10 £2.0260 1 £2.5000 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V185WAAA DISTRI # 1145-1189-ND","1name":"Delta Electronics Inc","2name":"LED DRIVER CC/CV AC/DC 54V 3.45A","3name":"23 In Stock","4name":"100 £37.7587 50 £41.1914 25 £43.9376 10 £44.6240 5 £46.6840 1 £48.0600 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"SIT3808AI-22-25NE-54.000000Y DISTRI # SIT3808AI-22-25NE-54.000000Y-ND","1name":"SiTime Corporation","2name":"OSC MEMS VCXO 54.0000MHZ LVCMOS","3name":"Temporarily Out of Stock","4name":"1000 £3.9582","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"SIT3808AI-22-25NE-54.000000T DISTRI # SIT3808AI-22-25NE-54.000000T-ND","1name":"SiTime Corporation","2name":"OSC MEMS VCXO 54.0000MHZ LVCMOS","3name":"Temporarily Out of Stock","4name":"3000 £3.9582","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"SIT3808AC-DF-33NE-54.000000Y DISTRI # SIT3808AC-DF-33NE-54.000000Y-ND","1name":"SiTime Corporation","2name":"OSC MEMS VCXO 54.0000MHZ LVCMOS","3name":"Temporarily Out of Stock","4name":"1000 £5.7821","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"SIT3808AC-DF-33NE-54.000000T DISTRI # SIT3808AC-DF-33NE-54.000000T-ND","1name":"SiTime Corporation","2name":"OSC MEMS VCXO 54.0000MHZ LVCMOS","3name":"Temporarily Out of Stock","4name":"3000 £5.7821","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V185WAAA","1name":"Delta Electronics Inc","2name":"54V 185W IP65 VR ADJUST","3name":"456","4name":"$68.4714","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V185WAAA","1name":"Delta Electronics Inc","2name":"54V 185W IP65 VR ADJUST","3name":"20","4name":"$61.5800","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V150WAAA","1name":"Delta Electronics Inc","2name":"54V 150W IP65 VR ADJUST","3name":"506","4name":"$64.9857","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V150WAAA","1name":"Delta Electronics Inc","2name":"54V 150W IP65 VR ADJUST","3name":"19","4name":"$58.4700","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V150WDAA","1name":"Delta Electronics Inc","2name":"54V 150W IP67 DIMMING","3name":"506","4name":"$64.9857","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V150WDAA","1name":"Delta Electronics Inc","2name":"54V 150W IP67 DIMMING","3name":"20","4name":"$58.4700","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V185WDAA","1name":"Delta Electronics Inc","2name":"54V 185W IP67 DIMMING","3name":"20","4name":"$61.5900","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V185WDAA","1name":"Delta Electronics Inc","2name":"54V 185W IP67 DIMMING","3name":"510","4name":"$68.4714","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V185WACA DISTRI # LNE-54V185WACA","1name":"Eltek","2name":"LED DRVR Module 1-CH IP65 58V 3.45A (Alt: LNE-54V185WACA) RoHS: Compliant","3name":"Europe - 20","4name":"1 €61.4380 100 €50.0606 1000 €45.0545 1 €61.4380 10 €56.3182 25 €54.0654 50 €51.9860 100 €50.0606 500 €48.2727 1000 €45.0545 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"PME264NE5470MR30 DISTRI # PME264NE5470MR30","1name":"KEMET Corporation","2name":"Cap Paper 0.047uF 1500V 20% (30.5 X 10.5 X 17mm) Radial 25.4mm 85Â°C Bulk (Alt: PME264NE5470MR30) RoHS: Compliant","3name":"Europe - 800","4name":"100 €1.4116 400 €1.1103 1000 €0.9881 100 €1.4116 200 €1.1926 400 €1.1103 600 €1.0449 1000 €0.9881 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"PME264NE5470MR04 DISTRI # PME264NE5470MR04","1name":"KEMET Corporation","2name":"Cap Paper 0.047uF 1500V 20% (30.5 X 10.5 X 17mm) Radial 25.4mm 85Â°C Bulk - Bulk (Alt: PME264NE5470MR04) RoHS: Compliant","3name":"Americas - 118","4name":"1 $1.4331 100 $1.3236 1000 $1.2562 1 $1.4331 10 $1.4126 25 $1.3927 50 $1.3733 100 $1.3236 500 $1.2774 1000 $1.2562 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V150WDAA DISTRI # LNE-54V150WDAA","1name":"Eltek","2name":"LED DRVR Module 1-CH IP67 58V 2.8A - Trays (Alt: LNE-54V150WDAA) RoHS: Not Compliant","3name":"Americas - 0","4name":"10 $71.0781 40 $68.9242 100 $65.9275 10 $71.0781 20 $69.9846 40 $68.9242 60 $67.8955 100 $65.9275 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V150WACA DISTRI # LNE-54V150WACA","1name":"Eltek","2name":"LED DRVR Module 1-CH IP65 58V 2.8A (Alt: LNE-54V150WACA) RoHS: Compliant","3name":"Europe - 0","4name":"100 €54.9188 220 €50.6943 1000 €43.9351 100 €54.9188 120 €52.7221 220 €50.6943 500 €47.0733 1000 €43.9351 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V150WDCA DISTRI # LNE-54V150WDCA","1name":"Eltek","2name":"LED DRVR Module 1-CH Analog IP67 54V 2.8A (Alt: LNE-54V150WDCA) RoHS: Compliant","3name":"Europe - 0","4name":"100 €55.8417 220 €51.5461 1000 €44.6733 100 €55.8417 120 €53.6080 220 €51.5461 500 €47.8643 1000 €44.6733 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V185WDCA DISTRI # LNE-54V185WDCA","1name":"Eltek","2name":"LED DRVR Module 1-CH Analog IP67 54V 3.45A (Alt: LNE-54V185WDCA) RoHS: Compliant","3name":"Europe - 0","4name":"100 €57.2560 220 €52.8517 1000 €45.8048 100 €57.2560 120 €54.9658 220 €52.8517 500 €49.0766 1000 €45.8048 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"PME264NE5470MR30 DISTRI # PME264NE5470MR30","1name":"KEMET Corporation","2name":"Cap Paper 0.047uF 1500V 20% (30.5 X 10.5 X 17mm) Radial 25.4mm 85Â°C Bulk - Bulk (Alt: PME264NE5470MR30) RoHS: Not Compliant","3name":"Americas - 0","4name":"1 $3.1913 100 $1.7678 1000 $1.3192 1 $3.1913 10 $2.5964 25 $2.5899 50 $2.2601 100 $1.7678 500 $1.5035 1000 $1.3192 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"SIT3808AC-DF-33NE-54.000000T DISTRI # SIT3808AC-DF-33NE-54.000000T","1name":"SiTime Corporation","2name":"HIGH PERFORMANCE PROGRAMMABLE MEMS VCXO, -20 TO 70C, 7050, 10PPM, 3.3V, 54MHZ, NC, 100 PPM PR, SMD - Tape and Reel (Alt: SIT3808AC-DF-33NE-54.000000T) RoHS: Compliant","3name":"Americas - 0","4name":"3000 $7.8421 12000 $7.5443 30000 $7.1807 3000 $7.8421 6000 $7.7403 12000 $7.5443 18000 $7.3580 30000 $7.1807 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"SIT3808AI-22-25NE-54.000000Y DISTRI # SIT3808AI-22-25NE-54.000000Y","1name":"SiTime Corporation","2name":"HIGH PERFORMANCE PROGRAMMABLE MEMS VCXO, -40 TO 85C, 3225, 25PPM, 2.5V, 54MHZ, NC, 100 PPM PR, SMD - Tape and Reel (Alt: SIT3808AI-22-25NE-54.000000Y) RoHS: Compliant","3name":"Americas - 0","4name":"1000 $5.3684 4000 $5.1646 10000 $4.9157 1000 $5.3684 2000 $5.2987 4000 $5.1646 6000 $5.0370 10000 $4.9157 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"SIT3808AI-22-25NE-54.000000T DISTRI # SIT3808AI-22-25NE-54.000000T","1name":"SiTime Corporation","2name":"HIGH PERFORMANCE PROGRAMMABLE MEMS VCXO, -40 TO 85C, 3225, 25PPM, 2.5V, 54MHZ, NC, 100 PPM PR, SMD - Tape and Reel (Alt: SIT3808AI-22-25NE-54.000000T) RoHS: Compliant","3name":"Americas - 0","4name":"3000 $5.3684 12000 $5.1646 30000 $4.9157 3000 $5.3684 6000 $5.2987 12000 $5.1646 18000 $5.0370 30000 $4.9157 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"SIT3808AC-DF-33NE-54.000000Y DISTRI # SIT3808AC-DF-33NE-54.000000Y","1name":"SiTime Corporation","2name":"HIGH PERFORMANCE PROGRAMMABLE MEMS VCXO, -20 TO 70C, 7050, 10PPM, 3.3V, 54MHZ, NC, 100 PPM PR, SMD - Tape and Reel (Alt: SIT3808AC-DF-33NE-54.000000Y) RoHS: Compliant","3name":"Americas - 0","4name":"1000 $7.8421 4000 $7.5443 10000 $7.1807 1000 $7.8421 2000 $7.7403 4000 $7.5443 6000 $7.3580 10000 $7.1807 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"PME264NE5470MR30 DISTRI # 2729016","1name":"KEMET Corporation","2name":"CAP, SUP, X2, MP, 0.047UF, 660V, RAD RoHS: Compliant","3name":"80","4name":"1 £2.9700 5 £2.5100 10 £2.0000 20 £1.8300 40 £1.6000 100 £1.2800 500 £1.1200 1000 £1.0200 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"PME264NE5470MR30 DISTRI # 3110992P","1name":"KEMET Corporation","2name":"Paper capacitor 47nF 660Vac, 1.5kVdc, BX","3name":"490","4name":"50 £1.7800 250 £1.3340 1000 £1.0380 2500 £1.0020 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"PME264NE5470MR30 DISTRI # 3110992","1name":"KEMET Corporation","2name":"Paper capacitor 47nF 660Vac, 1.5kVdc, PK","3name":"200","4name":"5 £2.5180 50 £1.7800 250 £1.3340 1000 £1.0380 2500 £1.0020 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V150WDAA DISTRI # 108-LNE-54V150WDAA","1name":"Delta Electronics Inc","2name":"LED Power Supplies 54VDC, 150W, IP67 with Dimming RoHS: Compliant","3name":"6","4name":"1 $59.9600 5 $58.2500 10 $55.6800 20 $54.8200 50 $51.3900 100 $47.1100 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V185WAAA DISTRI # 108-LNE-54V185WAAA","1name":"Delta Electronics Inc","2name":"LED Power Supplies 54VDC, 185W, IP65 with Adjustable VR RoHS: Compliant","3name":"10","4name":"1 $63.1700 5 $61.3600 10 $58.6500 20 $57.7500 50 $54.1400 100 $49.6300 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V150WAAA DISTRI # 108-LNE-54V150WAAA","1name":"Delta Electronics Inc","2name":"LED Power Supplies 54VDC, 150W, IP65 with Adjustable VR RoHS: Compliant","3name":"9","4name":"1 $59.9600 5 $58.2500 10 $55.6800 20 $54.8200 50 $51.3900 100 $47.1100 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V185WDAA DISTRI # 108-LNE-54V185WDAA","1name":"Delta Electronics Inc","2name":"LED Power Supplies 54VDC, 185W, IP67 with Dimming RoHS: Compliant","3name":"3","4name":"1 $63.1700 5 $61.3600 10 $58.6500 20 $57.7500 50 $54.1400 100 $49.6300 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"PME264NE5470MR30 DISTRI # 80-PME264NE5470MR30","1name":"KEMET Corporation","2name":"Film Capacitors 660vac 0.047uF 20% LS 25.4mm RoHS: Compliant","3name":"0","4name":"1 $3.2900 10 $2.6700 50 $2.3300 100 $2.0400 200 $1.7500 500 $1.5500 1000 $1.3600 2500 $1.3100 5000 $1.2600 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V150WDAA","1name":"Delta Products Corporation","2name":"LNE Series 150 W 2.8 A 54 V Output Max CB Certified LED Driver Module RoHS: Compliant","3name":"10 BOX","4name":"1 $48.9400","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V185WDAA","1name":"Delta Products Corporation","2name":"LNE Series 185 W 3.45 A 54 V Output Max CB Certified LED Driver Module RoHS: Compliant","3name":"10 BOX","4name":"1 $51.5600","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"NE542N","1name":"Signetics","2name":" ","3name":"16","4name":"5 $4.5000 2 $6.0000 1 $9.0000","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"NE544N","1name":"Signetics","2name":"Motor Controller Circuit, 14 Pin, DIP","3name":"809","4name":"287 $0.6250 51 $0.7000 1 $2.0000","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"NE544N","1name":"Signetics","2name":"Motor Controller Circuit, 14 Pin, DIP","3name":"3","4name":"4 $1.4000 1 $1.7500","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"NE546A","1name":"Signetics","2name":"AUDIO TUNER, PDIP14","3name":"9","4name":" ","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"NE542N","1name":"Signetics","2name":" ","3name":"20","4name":"1 $6.7200 5 $4.3680 13 $3.3600","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"NE540H","1name":"Signetics","2name":" ","3name":"10","4name":" ","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"PME264NE5470MR30 DISTRI # 14AC4882","1name":"KEMET Corporation","2name":"CAP, SUP, X2, MP, 0.047UF, 660V, RAD, Capacitance:0.047 F, Suppression Class:X2, Voltage Rating X:660V, Voltage Rating Y:-, Capacitor Dielectric Type:Paper (MP), Capacitance Tolerance: 20%, Product Range:PME264 Series, dv/dt , RoHS Compliant: Yes","3name":"80","4name":"1 $2.4200 10 $1.9800 25 $1.8300 50 $1.6700 100 $1.4800 500 $1.3300 1000 $1.1700 2500 $1.0400 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"PME264NE5470MR30 DISTRI # 2729016","1name":"KEMET Corporation","2name":"CAP, SUP, X2, MP, 0.047UF, 660V, RAD","3name":"80","4name":"1 $4.2800 5 $3.6160 10 $2.8800 20 $2.6300 40 $2.3000 100 $1.8400 500 $1.6100 1000 $1.4700 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"NE545B","1name":" ","2name":"INSTOCK","3name":"20","4name":" ","5name":"RFQ"},{"0name":"PME264NE5470MR30","1name":"KEMET Corporation","2name":"Film Capacitors 660vac 0.047uF 20% LS 25.4mm RoHS: Compliant","3name":"Americas -","4name":" ","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"PME264NE5470MR30","1name":"KEMET Corporation","2name":"Film Capacitors 660vac 0.047uF 20% LS 25.4mm RoHS: Compliant","3name":"Europe - 0","4name":" ","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V185WAAA DISTRI # LNE54V185WAAA","1name":"Delta Power","2name":" ","3name":"4","4name":"1 $60.1500 10 $55.5200 20 $52.3000 25 $48.1200 50 $46.2700 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V150WAAA DISTRI # LNE54V150WAAA","1name":"Delta Power","2name":" ","3name":"4","4name":"1 $57.1000 10 $52.7100 20 $49.6500 25 $45.6800 50 $43.9200 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V185WAAA DISTRI # DLTA-0003655","1name":"Delta Electronics Inc","2name":"Unidentified","3name":"20","4name":"1 $80.0083 5 $72.3479 10 $68.6074","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V150WAAA DISTRI # DLTA-0003688","1name":"Delta Electronics Inc","2name":"Unidentified","3name":"19","4name":"1 $75.9338 5 $68.6636 10 $65.1135","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V150WDAA DISTRI # DLTA-0003689","1name":"Delta Electronics Inc","2name":"Unidentified","3name":"20","4name":"1 $75.9338 5 $68.6636 10 $65.1135","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V185WDAA DISTRI # DLTA-0003690","1name":"Delta Electronics Inc","2name":"Unidentified","3name":"20","4name":"1 $80.0083 5 $72.3479 10 $68.6074","5name":"Buy Now"}]';


$arr = json_decode( $str, TRUE );

foreach( $arr as $el )
{
    echo '<p>' . $el['0name'] . '<br />' . 
        $el['1name'] . '<br />' . 
        $el['2name'] . '<br />' . 
        $el['3name'] . '<br />' . 
        $el['4name'] . '<br />' . 
        $el['5name'] . '</p>';
}
```

In Javascript use Javascript's JSON.parse():

```
var str = '[{"0name":"LNE-54V150WAAA DISTRI # 1145-1187-ND","1name":"Delta Electronics Inc","2name":"LED DRIVER CC/CV AC/DC 54V 2.8A","3name":"56 In Stock","4name":"100 £35.8441 50 £39.1026 25 £41.7096 10 £42.3620 5 £44.3160 1 £45.6200 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V150WDAA DISTRI # 1145-1188-ND","1name":"Delta Electronics Inc","2name":"LED DRIVER CC/CV AC/DC 54V 2.8A","3name":"53 In Stock","4name":"100 £35.8441 50 £39.1026 25 £41.7096 10 £42.3620 5 £44.3160 1 £45.6200 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"LNE-54V185WDAA DISTRI # 1145-1190-ND","1name":"Delta Electronics Inc","2name":"LED DRIVER CC/CV AC/DC 54V 3.45A","3name":"49 In Stock","4name":"100 £37.7587 50 £41.1914 25 £43.9376 10 £44.6240 5 £46.6840 1 £48.0600 See More","5name":"Buy Now"},{"0name":"PME264NE5470MR30 DISTRI # 399-7467-ND","1name":"KEMET Corporation","2name":"CAP FILM 0.047UF 20% 660VAC RAD","3name":"26 In Stock","4name":"5000 £0.9579 2500 £0.9948 1000 £1.0316 500 £1.1790 100 £1.5474 10 £2.0260 1 £2.5000 See More","5name":"Buy Now"}]';

var obj = JSON.parse( str );

for ( var i = 0, l = obj.length; i < l; i++ ) {
    alert( obj[ i ]['0name'] );
}
```

If you're using jQuery, looping through the array of objects can be done with $.each:

```
$.each( obj, function(i,x){
  alert( x['0name'] )
});
```

### Update

This is why you were getting the error regarding "invalid argument" ...

It turns out that toolfolks.com is outputing what you think is json, but since they are not serving it properly, it's coming in with HTML entities, and a bunch of extra whitespace. You don't see that when you look at in in your browser, but trust me it's there. So, to accomodate for their lunacy:

```
<?php

$json_response = file_get_contents('http://toolfolks.com/techy/parsefindchips2.php');

// Remove HTML entities
$json_response = html_entity_decode( $json_response );

// Remove the white space
$replaced = preg_replace('/\s\s+/', ' ', $json_response);

$arr = json_decode( $replaced, TRUE );

foreach( $arr as $el )
{
    echo '<p>' . $el['0name'] . '<br />' . 
        $el['1name'] . '<br />' . 
        $el['2name'] . '<br />' . 
        $el['3name'] . '<br />' . 
        $el['4name'] . '<br />' . 
        $el['5name'] . '</p>';
}
```

I definitely deserve extra points here :)

Comment: I have formatted a long string in Json format in my PHP file here. http://toolfolks.com/techy/parsefindchips2.php. I copy and paste into the Json Parser and all looks okay. When I add $arr = json_decode( $str, TRUE );

foreach( $arr as $el )
{
    echo '<p>' . $el['0name'] . '<br />' . 
        $el['1name'] . '<br />' . 
        $el['2name'] . '<br />' . 
        $el['3name'] . '<br />' . 
        $el['4name'] . '<br />' . 
        $el['5name'] . '</p>';
} I get error Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: `See updated answer.` The problem is that the json supplied by toolfolks.com is not really json. When you copy and paste, your not copying the problem, because the problem is in the raw response. You can verify this if you check "view source" in your browser, and look at the toolfolks.com URL. The best solution is to get in touch with toolfolks.com and have them fix this on their end, because you shouldn't have to parse broken json.